# Edit Cell Type From Exported Excel Sheet with PHP, SQL and HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, session

i wanted to export data from database to excel sheet but i have a problem that the mobile number came in the cells without the '0' in the beginning so i want to edit the cell type to text with code?

```
<?php 
session_name('database');
session_start();
$file = $_SESSION['dbc'];
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Database</h1><br>
    <p><?='Trainer Name: '.$_SESSION['dbtn'];?></p>
    <p><?='Center: '.$_SESSION['dbc'];?></p>
    <p><?='Round Starting Date: '.$_SESSION['dbd'];?></p>
    <p><?='Program: '.$_SESSION['dbp'];?></p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
                    $main_link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','disc');
                    $n = 1;
                    $con = mysqli_query($main_link, "SELECT name, email, mobile FROM test");
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con)) {
                        echo "<tr><td>{$n}</td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['email']}</td><td>{$row['mobile']}</td></tr>"; $n++;}?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

is there a way to save the file.xlsx to be saved in new version ?

Comment: Please add the code that writes the xlsx file, and show the expected result (short version). Also, plese clarify what you mean by *is there a way to save the file.xlsx to be saved in new version ?*. What is "new version"?

Comment: Are you writing an xlsx file, or a CSV to be imported into Excel?

Comment: @SloanThrasher 'header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");' xls and want to save it xlsx but when i change the name it gives an error

Comment: Update your question with the code that generates the xls instead of creating an html table. You might consider that exporting a csv is much easier, and imports into Excel easily.

Comment: @SloanThrasher i already copied it from the code so you can find it up there but my main problem is how to edit cell type in excel by code to show the zero before the mobile no. and how to make the csv and will it help to edit the cell type?

Comment: Your code generates an HTML page with a table. It does **not** create a csv file.